# fatal error : Index Out of Range : Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have JSON image.

```
let imagestring : String? = (myData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Post_mid_image") as? String

if imagestring != nil{
    let imageTrueString = "https://www.zdoof.com/" + imagestring!
    self.imageStringArray.append(imageTrueString )
    print(self.imageStringArray)
}
```

When I am trying to put it on table view:

```
let myImage = cell.viewWithTag(30) as! UIImageView
let myImageString : String? = imageStringArray[indexPath.row]

if myImageString != nil{
    let ImageUrl = URL.init(string: myImageString!)

    myImage.kf.setImage(with: ImageUrl)
}
```

It is showing an error like:

> fatal error : Index Out of Range

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You didn't post the code for your `numberOfRowsForSection:` method, but what is happening here is that you are trying to display a row that doesn't actually exist in your `imageStringArray`.

Comment: Then , what to do here please help

Comment: can you post the code that returns the number of rows for your table?

Answer (score 0):

Your number of rows method like this way

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageStringArray.count
    }
```

And use **if let** to avoid forcefully casting

```
if let myImage = cell.viewWithTag(30) as? UIImageView {
    if let myImageString = imageStringArray[indexPath.row] as? String {
        let ImageUrl = URL.init(string: myImageString!)
        myImage.kf.setImage(with: ImageUrl)

    }

}
```

**Updated:-**

```
if indexPath.row < imageStringArray.count {
    if let myImageString = imageStringArray[indexPath.row] as? String {
        let ImageUrl = URL.init(string: myImageString!)
        myImage.kf.setImage(with: ImageUrl)

    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to show some comments (Which may have comments and Images / only coments). If i will write                                                                   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageStringArray.count
    }                                                                                                                  It only showing the comment which have image

Comment: Answer updasted